# NSExtensionActivationRule: NsExtensionActivationSupportsImageWithMaxCount и NSExtensionActivationSupportsText не работают одновременно

Tags: swift, xcode

Пытаюсь настроить расширение приложения.
В качестве "принимаемых" значений могу принимать и изображения и просто текст и текст с изображением.
Если в настройках пишу либо NSExtensionActivationSupportsText либо NsExtensionActivationSupportsImageWithMaxCount то все работает нормально, но, если указать их одновременно то работает только текст. Что я делаю не так?

```
<dict>
        <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
        <dict>
            <key>IntentsSupported</key>
            <array>
                <string>INSendMessageIntent</string>
            </array>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsText</key>
                <integer>1</integer>
                <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebURLWithMaxCount</key>
                <integer>1</integer>
                <key>NsExtensionActivationSupportsImageWithMaxCount</key>
                <integer>1</integer>
            </dict>
        </dict>
        <key>NSExtensionMainStoryboard</key>
        <string>MainInterface</string>
        <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.apple.share-services</string>
    </dict>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо всем за помощь)
После разбора полетов ответ :

```
<key>NSExtension</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
        <dict>
            <key>IntentsSupported</key>
            <array>
                <string>INSendMessageIntent</string>
            </array>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
            <string>SUBQUERY (extensionItems, $extensionItem, SUBQUERY ( $extensionItem.attachments, $attachment,
                    ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.image" ||
                    ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.text"
                    ).@count == $extensionItem.attachments.@count
                    ).@count == 1
            </string>
        </dict>
        <key>NSExtensionMainStoryboard</key>
        <string>MainInterface</string>
        <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.apple.share-services</string>
    </dict>
```

P.S. Чем больше знакомлюсь с Apple - тем меньше раздражают гаишники...